# Pasar consulta sql puro a laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hola tengo una consulta algo compleja la cual necesito migrarla a Eloquent con laravel o QueryBuilder.
La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT tipo, id_banco, nro_operacion, anno,  
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 1 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Enero,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 2 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 3 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Marzo,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 4 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Abril,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 5 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Mayo,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 6 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Junio,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 7 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Julio,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 8 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Agosto,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 9 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Septiembre,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 10 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Octubre,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 11 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Noviembre,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 12 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Diciembre
from (
SELECT amortizacion.tipo, b.id as id_banco, amortizacion.nro_operacion,
MONTH(amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento) AS `mes`,
YEAR(amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento) AS `anno`,
Sum(amortizacion_detalle.valor_cuota) AS cuota
FROM
amortizacion_detalle
LEFT JOIN amortizacion ON amortizacion_detalle.amortizacion_id = amortizacion.id
LEFT JOIN banco AS b ON amortizacion.banco_id = b.id
WHERE
amortizacion.cliente_id = 10
GROUP BY
amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento
ORDER BY anno) as resultados
GROUP BY tipo, id_banco, nro_operacion, anno
```

**Este seria el resultado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que se necesita es poder realizarla en laravel trayendo o mejorando el resultando de dicha consulta.

```
$facs = DB::table('amortizacion_detalle')
    ->select(DB::raw('tipo, id_banco, nro_operacion, anno,  
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 1 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Enero,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 2 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 3 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Marzo,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 4 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Abril,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 5 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Mayo,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 6 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Junio,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 7 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Julio,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 8 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Agosto,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 9 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Septiembre,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 10 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Octubre,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 11 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Noviembre,
    sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 12 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Diciembre'))
    ->where('amortizacion.cliente_id', '=', $request->input('cliente_id'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega que has intentado

Comment: Listo. eso es lo realizado hasta el momento pero sin mejoras de lo que se quiere

Comment: Esto no me queda claro: **Pero lo que se necesita es poder realizarla en laravel trayendo o mejorando el resultando de dicha consulta** ¿buscas solo adaptar la consulta o el resultado de SQL es uno y el que te debe dar desde Laravel debe ser otro?

Comment: Solo es adaptar la consulta pero siempre hay quien dice eso se puede mejorar entonces por eso lo coloco si se pudiese mejorar pero lo que en realidad quiero es solo adaptación de la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera si usas **Query Builder**:

```
$resultados = DB::query()
            ->fromSub(function ($query) {
                $query->select(
                    'amortizacion.tipo',
                    'b.id AS id_banco',
                    'amortizacion.nro_operacion',
                    DB::raw('MONTH(amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento) AS mes'),
                    DB::raw('YEAR(amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento) AS anno'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(amortizacion_detalle.valor_cuota) AS cuota'))
                ->from('amortizacion_detalle')
                ->leftJoin('amortizacion', 'amortizacion.id', 'amortizacion_detalle.amortizacion_id')
                ->leftJoin('banco AS b', 'b.id', 'amortizacion.banco_id')
                ->where('amortizacion.cliente_id', 10)
                ->groupBy('amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento')
                ->orderBy('anno');
            }, 'resultados')
        ->select(
            'tipo',
            'id_banco',
            'nro_operacion',
            'anno',
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 1 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Enero'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 2 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 3 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Marzo'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 4 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Abril'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 5 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Mayo'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 6 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Junio'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 7 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Julio'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 8 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Agosto'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 9 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Septiembre'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 10 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Octubre'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 11 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Noviembre'),
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE  WHEN mes = 12 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Diciembre'))
        ->groupBy('tipo', 'id_banco', 'nro_operacion', 'anno')
        ->get();
```

Lo único nuevo sería el uso de [`fromSub($query, $alias)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23476) que fue un método agregado en la versión `5.6` (No sé qué versión de laravel estés usando).

La consulta habla por sí sola, la lógica es la misma.

Primero creas la subquery, que será de donde obtendras la data, posterior a eso, haces un select() para obtener las columnas de la subquery anterior y haces lo que ya habías definido.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió

Answer (score -1):

Esa consulta es demaciado larga de validar, y lentearas el sistema, mejor llevalos a un `procedimiento almacenado (store procedure)`

**Algo como esto**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Reporte_cliente (IN cliente_id INT)
BEGIN
SELECT tipo, id_banco, nro_operacion, anno,  
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 1 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Enero,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 2 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 3 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Marzo,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 4 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Abril,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 5 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Mayo,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 6 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Junio,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 7 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Julio,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 8 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Agosto,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 9 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Septiembre,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 10 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Octubre,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 11 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Noviembre,
sum(CASE  WHEN mes = 12 THEN cuota ELSE 0 END) AS Diciembre
from (
SELECT amortizacion.tipo, b.id as id_banco, amortizacion.nro_operacion,
MONTH(amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento) AS `mes`,
YEAR(amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento) AS `anno`,
Sum(amortizacion_detalle.valor_cuota) AS cuota
FROM
amortizacion_detalle
LEFT JOIN amortizacion ON amortizacion_detalle.amortizacion_id = amortizacion.id
LEFT JOIN banco AS b ON amortizacion.banco_id = b.id
WHERE
amortizacion.cliente_id = cliente_id
GROUP BY
amortizacion_detalle.fecha_vencimiento
ORDER BY anno) as resultados
GROUP BY tipo, id_banco, nro_operacion, anno
END
```

**invocas desde Laravel**

```
$cliente_id = 10;
$report = \DB::select('CALL Reporte_cliente (?)', array($cliente_id));
```

**$report** tendria tu lista de datos

Comment: ¿Bajo qué condiciones consideras que esta consultas *alentaria el sistema*?

Comment: Laravel tiene desactivado `Sentencias SQL` , ya que estos retornos tienen que ser paraseados a `Array` y estos llevados a **Objetos** `StdClass` y para estos parseos, `Eloquent / Query Builder` usaran PHP, teniendo `Mysql` que puede procesarlos

Comment: Umm es relativo, el performance de una query depende de mas aspectos donde también el mysql juega un papel relevante